# Hiding the particular section on a page using css

Tags: html, css

Hi i am having two divs with same classes and all in that i need to hide one div anchor tag.Here is the code for that

```css
.tribe-section.tribe-section-taxonomy.contactus:nth-child(n) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tribe-section tribe-section-taxonomy">
   <a href="http://teknotrait.com/carrolltonalive/contact/" class="contactus">Contact us</a>
   <h3>Event Categories</h3>
</div>
<div class="tribe-section tribe-section-taxonomy">
    <a href="http://teknotrait.com/carrolltonalive/contact/" class="contactus">Contact us</a>
    <h3>Event Tgas</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want hidden?

Comment: please be more specific about what you actually want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tribe-section.tribe-section-taxonomy:nth-child(4n) > .contactus {
  display: block !important;
}
.tribe-section.tribe-section-taxonomy:nth-child(4n+1) > .contactus {
  display: none !important;
}
```